# Responsive diagonal line in CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a diagonal line go from a bottom border, to a top border, behind a nav box and have two different background colours on each side of the diagonal.

And, to top it off, it needs to be responsive.

Hopefully this makes sense, if it doesn't, heres an image.

In the image, the bottom-left diagonal comes out too far, it would end in line with the left nav box element, so could use the location of each of the corners as anchors.

[image]

More than happy to use whatever method is proposed.

Thanks!

**EDIT** I can make a parallelogram in css pretty easy but it is not responsive.

```
#parallelogram {
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-40deg);
    background: red;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cbiggins/fVeDD/

**EDIT 2** Updated fiddle, now calculating angle and applying change on resize. Note this only works on Chrome (and Safari?) atm.

http://jsfiddle.net/cbiggins/fVeDD/5/

We might be leaving it now though, I'm not sure how feasible this is now with the time constraints we have in our current project.

Comment: If possible, can post `html`, `css`, `js` ?

Comment: I'd suggest making a solid div (skinny and long) then using CSS transformations to rotate it. How far to rotate would require a bit of math and JS.

Comment: Hi @DA.I have played with that a fair bit, I'm wondering if some kind of trapazoid shape would work. It's the positioning that I'm not getting right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css3 transformation something like below:

```
.border_div{
  width: 200px; // you may also need to apply position absolute
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can add diagonals but if I use rotate an element, not all of the background is coloured. This also doesn't address having the nav block on top. Would love as much detail as you can give. CSS is not my forte.

Comment: You need to use position absolute and place your border_div after the nav.

Comment: Ah yes, but if you rotate a rectangle it becomes a diamond. So, wont cover the background to the right. If I was to use a parallelogram of sorts, it might work?

Comment: the background layered div should be positioned relatively. then works perfect with absolute position.